# cmake preset configuration: invalid preset

Tags: cmake

Trying out CMake presets, falling at one of the very first hurdles.

I have this simple "CMakePresets.json" alongside my CMakeLists.txt

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "simple",
      "displayName": "simple"
    }
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
    {
      "name": "dev",
      "configurePreset": "simple"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my very simple CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.1)

project(hello)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# I want these supplied by the presets
# with QTDIR in the user specific presets
# as these will differ from dev person to
# dev person
# ------------------------------------
# set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
# set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
# set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
# set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
# set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{QTDIR})

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)

qt_add_qml_module(${PROJECT_NAME}
    URI qml
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES main.qml)
```

I then (on a clean setup) run

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. --preset=dev
```

But I always get the following error

> CMake Error: Could not read presets from
> /home/.../cmake/simple: Invalid preset

I get the same message if I try

```
cmake .. --list-presets
```

I either must be invoking `cmake` incorrectly, or there is something wrong with my JSON.

Can someone point out my mistake?

For instance:
Does the preset name from the CMakePresets.json need to match the project name in the CMakeLists.txt?
Keeping in mind that a CMakeLists.txt can build multiple targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before version `3` a configure preset **requires** to have fields `generator` and `binaryDir`. From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#configure-preset):

> `generator`
>
> An optional string representing the generator to use for the preset.
> If `generator` is not specified, it must be inherited from the `inherits` preset (unless this preset is `hidden`).
> In version 3 or above, this field may be omitted to fall back to regular generator discovery procedure.

> `binaryDir`
>
> An optional string representing the path to the output binary directory.
> This field supports macro expansion. If a relative path is specified, it is calculated relative to the source directory.
> If `binaryDir` is not specified, it must be inherited from the `inherits` preset (unless this preset is `hidden`).
> In version 3 or above, this field may be omitted.

See also https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cmake-invalid-preset/3538.

Comment: Thanks! I had the "binaryDir" in there at one point, but reduced my [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) too far.
I was missing the "generator" part from the outset. Didn't think CMake cared how the resulting makefile gets built.
Your linked article mentions validation against a scheme. Is that an online validation tool per chance?

Comment: At the beginning of the linked discourse there is a link to the the validator with the loaded scheme: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/qBO5hy21.

Comment: Hmmm, it would seem that the preset config I posted in this question validates OK against the "CMake Presets" on said linked page. The validation may need tightening down. Presumably a WIP?

Comment: Also, are presets somehow tied to a target in the CMakeLists?
Or can we only set global settings with CMake presets?